# How to trigger a 404 not found error message for live Wordpress homepage only?

Tags: http-status-code-404

I want to manually trigger a 404 error message on my live wordpress homepage for a couple of days.

I don’t want any of the posts to get affected.

How can I do it?

I want to remove my blog's homepage from a search engine. Noindex tag and blocking on robots.txt seems to take a lot more time than removing by 404 status message. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to remove your homepage temporarily from search engines?

Comment: Yes. But not with Robots.txt or noindex tag on HTML head. I want to let the search engine to know the page as 404.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to make the search engines know that the page is Error 404. But the other ways to remove page urgently from top search-engines are mentioned. I hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a page temporarily,and urgently, from **Google** you can [click here to open search console removal.](https://search.google.com/search-console/removals) And in case of **Bing** and **Yahoo**, you can use [click here to open Bing Content Removal tool.](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/searchconfig/blockurl)
And for the other search engines, you can add a `noindex` tag or `robots.txt`, and request re-indexing.